# CSS: img's inline-block alignment

Tags: html, css

For whatever reason this image is making the rest of the markup to not align within it's container, despite it is set to display inline-block.:

http://jsfiddle.net/ncQXD/

For you guys should be something simple. For me, I already spent days trying to solve this problem.

By the way, I do not want to use float. I do not fully know how to control their weirdness and do not have time atm to learn it. I'll appreciate if you could please not use them. HOWEVER, I can take a crash course on floats if you lead me to one that covers all their mishaps and such.

For now, I need to stick to a non-float css.

PS. The borders are just for "debugging" and are really not necesary

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_test2.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <img src="http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/938/imgbz.png" id="logo">
    <a href="#" id="logo_txt">Title goes here</a>
    <span id="social_media">Social media links</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
    border: 1px solid red;

    width: 800px;
    height: 123px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;

    background-color: rgb(181, 230, 29);
    }

#logo {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 172px;
    height: 123px;
    }


#logo_txt {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 100px;
    height: 123px;
    }
#social_media {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;

    width: 300px;
    height: 123px;
    text-align: right;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to fix this is to add `vertical-align: top` to the `#logo` styles.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
vertical-align:text-top;
```

to your image style, `vertical-align:top;` would work too but  I used text top since its aligning against text

The default vertical alignment is baseline, which would align the bottom of the image with the text in the other divs.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/ncQXD/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Hi i if you used `display inline-block` in any way than define one properties

```
vertical-align:top;
```

Because by default properties is `vertical-align:middle;` so than define `verticle-align` properties.

and now sam think in `img` **tag**  Define your **img tag** properties in your **css** `verticel-align:top`
.

Answer (score 0):

`float` the elements to the left and everything works: http://jsfiddle.net/ncQXD/1/

I added this CSS:

```
#header > * {
    float: left;
}

#header {
    overflow: auto;
}​
```

Comment: -1 The poster stated several times that he did not want to use float.

Comment: I see no reason for that restriction. Do you?

Comment: The poster stated the restriction for their own reasons.